# How to use a comma that differentiates between a noun and a verb

Tags: punctuation, commas

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

> I love reading my books and movies.

or

> I love reading, my books and movies.

What if **reading** is used as a noun? Name of a hobby.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>I love reading my books and movies.
```

or

```
>I love reading, my books and movies.
```

First, you are using the wrong terms: "reading" is not a noun in either sentence.

I am **reading** a book -> reading = **present participle.**

I love **reading** -> reading = **gerund.**

The **reading** of the book started at 4 o'clock. -> reading = **verbal noun**.

Next: The example is very poorly constructed. Obviously, you do not **read** movies, although the sentences seems to say that you do.

Both **reading my books** (gerund phrase) and movies (noun) are objects of the verb "love" and are therefore both substantives.

The object should not be separated from its verb by a comma - so do **not** use a comma.

There are two possible corrections.

1. You can change the order of the objects (simple objects should come first)

*I love movies and reading my books.*

Or 2. you can change the object into something that you can read:

*I love reading my books and **poems**.*

Comment: Isn't it possible that 'reading' functions like a noun, and 'reading a book', noun phrase?  I think it is possible.

Comment: @RamPillai "reading" "functions like a noun because it is a gerund, and gerunds "function like nouns"... but they are not nouns.

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences are correct and meaningful although the second one communicates thoughts that are not usually found side by side; you have to parse them as follows.

- I love | reading my books | and | movies. (*two coordinated objects:* "***reading my books***", "***movies***)
- I love | reading,| my books | and | movies. (*three coordinated objects:* "***reading***", ***my books***", "***movies***)

There is a difficulty as the interest usually one has in books is the activity of reading them and/or their particular content; as "I love my books" might be said by some people so as to mean "I love the content of my books.", that is, what they can communicate to a reader, or maybe not so uncommonly "I love the particular look of my books, the particular editions of them."  (for instance original leather bound editions), the reader is therefore exposed to a vague and incomplete thought. If the context clears this difficulty, before or immediately after, then the second sentence becomes stylistically acceptable.